# What does man command do in broader sense?

Tags: command-line, manpage

While reading about Linux, I got the following about `man` (manual) pages:

> The man pages are the most often-used source of Linux documentation.
>   They provide in-depth documentation about many programs and utilities
>   as well as other topics, including configuration files, system calls,
>   library routines, and the kernel.

I am new to this flavor, so can someone explain me the specific jargons like:

- *configuration files* (why and how are they used)
- *system calls* (I guess it is related to the system calls invoked while executing these commands - correct me if I am wrong)
- what are library routines associated with any command?
- and how kernel information is related to any command?

I tried some of these commands as

```
man more
```

but again its too long and difficult for me to totally get it: is there any easy reference for beginners like me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux distributions and their programs come with lots of documentation. Some are in HTML format, others in simple text files, most install so-called man pages.

Man pages, long manual pages, can be seen as chapters of a reference manual.

- > configuration files (why and how are they used)

  Config files configure the initial settings for programs, lots are in /etc
- > system calls (I guess it is related to the system calls invoked while
  >   executing these commands - correct me if I am wrong)

  A system call is how a program requests a service from the kernel
- > what are library routines associated with any command?

  Those are routines that the specified command uses from certain libraries.
- > and how kernel information is related to any command?

  ... now it gets tough, as you really need to know about operating systems and their inner workings in depth.

> I tried some of these commands as `man more`, but again its too long and difficult for me to totally get it: is there any easy reference for beginners like me?

#### Conclusion

Think of it this way: You want to know how to use the command `more`. You can now either go to the library and get a book about the usage of this command. Or you can type `man more` and the contents of the book are displayed on your screen.

If you're new to computing or Linux, then the book / manpage will contain lots of jargon you don't understand, but that's inherent to learning something new.

Comment: thanx @Jan, can you tell me which type of software -installation needs to deal with .config files,,I mean not all packages require this,which can directly be installed through repositories,

Comment: @jazzz It is not clear what you are asking. Please ask a new question about config files.